# How to create an array of items which are members of a specific group within the bookmarks toolbar?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

For reference:
[Add-on SDK -> Low-Level APIs -> places/bookmarks#Searching for bookmarks](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Low-Level_APIs/places_bookmarks#Searching_for_bookmarks)

It does not work:

```
let { search, Bookmark, Group, Seperator, save, remove, MENU, TOOLBAR, UNSORTED } = require("sdk/places/bookmarks");

var du = [];
search({ group: TOOLBAR }).on("data", function (item) {
    if (item.group.title == "workMode990") {
        du[du.length] = item;
        console.log("mary", du);
        //item.group = UNSORTED;
        //save(item);
    }
});
```

How to create an array, such as the order of the bookmarks panel?

Comment: How is is that this is not working (i.e. what are you getting that you are not expecting)? What are you expecting to get?  What is your console output? You do not show how/when you are using the data in `du`.  Thus, it is really not possible for us to evaluate if you are consuming the generated data correctly.

Comment: The most common problem which would be causing someone problems here is that [search()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Low-Level_APIs/places_bookmarks#search%28queries.2C_options%29) is asynchronous. This means that immediately after this code the contents of `du` are not yet valid. If you are not accounting for this function being asynchronous, then it would appear to you that it is not working.

Answer (score 1):

Your code may, or may not, work as written.  It is probable that you are not accounting for the fact that the [`search()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Low-Level_APIs/places_bookmarks#search%28queries.2C_options%29) function is asynchronous.

I would probably code it a bit differently than you have:

```
let { search, Bookmark, Group, Separator,
              save, remove, MENU, TOOLBAR, UNSORTED } = require("sdk/places/bookmarks");
//Note: your code has a spelling error in the above line: Seperator should be Separator

var du;
var duValid = false;
search({ group: TOOLBAR }).on("end", function (searchResultArray) {
    //This is executed when the search has completed.
    //  searchResultArray is an  ordered list of bookmark items.
    du = searchResultArray.filter( function(resultItem) {
        //When done testing (console logging), only the following line is needed:
        //return resultItem.group.title === "workMode990";
        if (resultItem.group.title === "workMode990") {
            console.log("Valid resultItem: ", resultItem);
            return true;
        } //else
        console.log("Rejected resultItem: ", resultItem);
        return false;
    });
    duValid = true;
    //du is valid here.  Perform whatever else you are going to do with it here, or
    //  call a function that continues processing.
});
//du is not valid here.
```

The reasons I would use [`search().on("end")`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Low-Level_APIs/places_bookmarks#end) instead of [`search().on("data")`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Low-Level_APIs/places_bookmarks#data) are:

1. You need to catch the `search().on("end")` event anyway to know when your search is complete and you have all valid data. If you don't catch this event, then you have no way of knowing when your search is complete.
2. Using `search().on("data")` results in your code handling an event for each data item found.  There is no real need for you to handle it this way, and it results in the additional overhead of processing each event instead of a single event. If you think you might be memory limited, it might be a better solution. However, doing so may not actually save any memory depending on the internal processing of the search.

I added printing the rejected search result items to the console in addition to the valid ones.  If we are going to do logging for debugging, we might as well log both to verify that the search is returning the expected results, and the expected ones are being accepted/rejected.

A significant reason I added logging to the console of the rejected `resultItem`s is that I expect that you will end up with nothing in `du` given your current logic.  While I have not tested it, my expectation is that your `search({ group: TOOLBAR })` should return all bookmarks which are in the bookmark toolbar.  However, you then filter out all bookmarks which are not in the `workMode990` group. This should filter out all of the bookmarks as that is not the TOOLBAR.

Because you have not answered my original question of "What are you expecting to get?" it is not possible to determine what it is you are actually attempting to accomplish. Thus, it is necessary to guess.

I suspect, that what you are attempting to do is find all of the bookmarks in the `workMode990` group.  If that is the case the following should do that:

```
let { search, Bookmark, Group, Separator,
              save, remove, MENU, TOOLBAR, UNSORTED } = require("sdk/places/bookmarks");
//Note: your code has a spelling error in the above line: Seperator should be Separator

var du;
var duValid = false;
search({ group: "workMode990" }).on("end", function (searchResultArray) {
    //This is executed when the search has completed.
    //  searchResultArray is an  ordered list of bookmark items.
    du = searchResultArray;
    duValid = true;
    //du is valid here.  Perform whatever else you are going to do with it here, or
    //  call a function that continues processing.
});
//du is not valid here.
```

Comment: `search({ group: TOOLBAR }).on("end", function (searchResultArray) {/*whatever*/}); `...  Completely does not work.
Is this a bug API?

Comment: When I use the `group: TOOLBAR`. Do not pay anything at all.
When I use the example.`tags` or `query` `search({query: "mozilla"}).on("end", function (searchResultArray) {/ * whatever * /});
It searches, but only a bookmark. Groups does not search.

Comment: @lukaszpolowczyk, (answer updated) What you want to accomplish is not clear. Please explain what you are trying to accomplish with your query (i.e. what combined criteria are you wanting to match, be explicit)? I asked this in my first comment to your question (although not as explicitly). Please [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/29111341/edit) to include this information. I ask this now, and asked this originally, because it appeared the query you were using and what you were doing with it did not match (which could be your problem). Without this info, everyone has to guess.